# Structure and function of the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, semantic-roles

**She felt unreal as the voice informed her of the subway accident - the shoving crowd, Arthur pushed from the platform in front of the train.**

It is a sentence of a short story, Button, Button, by Richard Matheson. The context of this sentence reveals that it was actually Arthur who was thrown by the shoving crowd in front of the train but the above mentioned sentence shows that it was Arthur who pushed (someone) from the platform. What is the actual structure of the asked sentence and how does it function grammatically? The verb **pushed**, if used as intransitive, does not match the context. And what's the role of punctuation (,) after the phrase the shoving crowd?

Comment: what is the source of this sentence, please?

Comment: Please post the ENTIRE sentence and edit your question to reflect the change. It makes a BIG difference in this case.

Comment: What makes you think the sentence says Arthur was doing the pushing? Nothing at all in it suggests that.

Comment: She visualises the 'shoving crowd' and Arthur [being] pushed from the platform.

Comment: @Abid You have been asked a few questions as far back as 10 hrs ago. Please have the courtesy to answer them.